# Google maps in React without custom library: cannot read property setState of null

Tags: reactjs

I´m currently using google Maps in React without a library. I keep getting that error (cannot read property setState of null) which I know has to do with the use of "this" inside the function. I´m clueless as to how to solve it in this particular case.

Method

```
getGPS = () =>{
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      let start = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      this.setState({start: start})
    });
  } else {
    let start= {lat:"-34.603474", lng:"-58.381592"};
    this.setState({start: start})
  };
  this.calculateAndDisplayRoute()
}
```

Map component

```
<Map
id="myNewMap"
float="right"
width= "50%"
options={{
center: {lat: this.state.currentMarker[0].getPosition().lat(), lng: this.state.currentMarker[0].getPosition().lng()},
zoom: 18,
disableDefaultUI: true,
}}
onMapLoad={map => {
this.newMap = map;
{this.getGPS()}
} 
}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(position) {
      let start = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      this.setState({start: start})
    }
```

You are correct, it's the scope of `this`. JavaScript thinks you are referencing the `this` within the function.  If you update your function to an arrow function, the `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope is used, which will be your component.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      let start = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      this.setState({start: start})
    };
```

Comment: I feel so silly, I didn´t even realised there was another function inside my function. Thanks, man!

Comment: No problems! If you could accept my answer at your earliest convenience that would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)